# Facebook chat alert “Friend is using an application to access chat.”

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I am using the Facebook chat a lot but today something odd started happening. When I try to send my friends a message through the Facebook chat they will receive a pop up message saying something like

> Friend is using an application to
>   access chat. To send him a message,
>   you must change your settings to
>   enable friends using applications to
>   see you when you're online.

I am not using any type of third party application to chat with. I did so when I tried chatting through my iPad some time ago but right now I am using the official chat.

Has anyone experienced this error and / or does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: One of my friends choose to activate some setting which the popup suggested. Now, when my friend tries sending me a message it appears as I am offline.

Comment: An error with Facebook chat is "too localized"?

Comment: I had same issue. Just go to `Privacy Settings` > `Apps and Websites` > `How people bring your info to apps they use` > `Edit Settings` > Select `If I'm online`

Comment: @phwd I fail to see the reasoning for closing this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. `Privacy Settings` > `Ads, Apps and Websites` > `Edit Settings`
2. `How people bring your info to apps they use` > `Edit Settings`
3. `✓ If I'm online` > `Save Changes`

[Facebook.com - Privacy settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy)

Answer (score 1):

I found it this way: Account settings / Apps / Apps others use / If I'm online (unchecked -> checked).